# How to copy column data in excel by Apache poi?

Tags: apache-poi

Does anybody know how to copy a existing column data into a new sheet in a excel file or a new workbook by Apache poi? The data type is double and date.

Answer (score 1):

I attached the link below. They also provide mutiple different ways of doing it.

```
    import java.util.Collection;   
    import java.util.HashMap;   
    import java.util.Map;   
    import java.util.Set;   
    import java.util.TreeSet;   
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;   
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;   
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;   
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;   
    import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;   

    /**  
     *  
     * @author jk  
     * getted from http://jxls.cvs.sourceforge.net/jxls/jxls/src/java/org/jxls/util/Util.java?revision=1.8&view=markup  
     * by Leonid Vysochyn   
     * and modified (adding styles copying)  
     * modified by Philipp Löpmeier (replacing deprecated classes and methods, using generic types)  
     */  
    public class Util {   

        public static void copySheets(HSSFSheet newSheet, HSSFSheet sheet){   
            copySheets(newSheet, sheet, true);   
        }   

        public static void copySheets(HSSFSheet newSheet, HSSFSheet sheet, boolean copyStyle){   
            int maxColumnNum = 0;   
            Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap = (copyStyle) ? new HashMap<Integer, HSSFCellStyle>() : null;   
            for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {   
                HSSFRow srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);   
                HSSFRow destRow = newSheet.createRow(i);   
                if (srcRow != null) {   
                    Util.copyRow(sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);   
                    if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {   
                        maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();   
                    }   
                }   
            }   
            for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {   
                newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));   
            }   
        }   

        public static void copyRow(HSSFSheet srcSheet, HSSFSheet destSheet, HSSFRow srcRow, HSSFRow destRow, Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {   
            Set<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions = new TreeSet<CellRangeAddress>();   
            destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());   
            for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {   
                HSSFCell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j);   
                HSSFCell newCell = destRow.getCell(j);   
                if (oldCell != null) {   
                    if (newCell == null) {   
                        newCell = destRow.createCell(j);   
                    }   
                    copyCell(oldCell, newCell, styleMap);   
                    CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = getMergedRegion(srcSheet, srcRow.getRowNum(), (short)oldCell.getColumnIndex());   
                    if (mergedRegion != null) {   
                        CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(mergedRegion.getFirstRow(), mergedRegion.getFirstColumn(), mergedRegion.getLastRow(), mergedRegion.getLastColumn());   
                        if (isNewMergedRegion(newMergedRegion, mergedRegions)) {   
                            mergedRegions.add(newMergedRegion);   
                            destSheet.addMergedRegion(newMergedRegion);   
                        }   
                    }   
                }   
            }   

        }   

        public static void copyCell(HSSFCell oldCell, HSSFCell newCell, Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {   
            if(styleMap != null) {   
                if(oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()){   
                    newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());   
                } else{   
                    int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();   
                    HSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);   
                    if(newCellStyle == null){   
                        newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();   
                        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());   
                        styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);   
                    }   
                    newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);   
                }   
            }   
            switch(oldCell.getCellType()) {   
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:   
                    newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());   
                    break;   
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:   
                    newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());   
                    break;   
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:   
                    newCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);   
                    break;   
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:   
                    newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());   
                    break;   
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:   
                    newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());   
                    break;   
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:   
                    newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());   
                    break;   
                default:   
                    break;   
            }   

        }   

        public static CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(HSSFSheet sheet, int rowNum, short cellNum) {   
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {   
                CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);   
                if (merged.isInRange(rowNum, cellNum)) {   
                    return merged;   
                }   
            }   
            return null;   
        }   

        private static boolean isNewMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion, Collection<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions) {   
            return !mergedRegions.contains(newMergedRegion);   
        }   

    }
```

http://www.coderanch.com/t/420958/open-source/Copying-sheet-excel-file-another